# Сгенерировать свойства для файла

Tags: c#

Я хочу создать список, который будет генерироваться рандомно (RNG)
`<string>, <string>, string>, <int>` - Куда можно занести список для каждого свойства?
Описание, название продукта, авторское право, версия файла.
Для каждого свойства файла идентичные данные!

```
"4Game", "Launcher", "Copyright (c) 2018", "1.0.0.264", - Первое свойства для файла
"Matroska", "Launcher", "Copyright (c) Matros 2020", "0.0.1.10", - Второе свойства для файла
"Tetris", "Application", "Copyright (c) 2000", "0.0.0.1", - Третье свойство для файла
```

Выше список должен генерироваться рандомно, типо если первый, чтобы все его параметры передались.
`P.S: Простите, не знаю как правильно донести мысль вопроса)`

---

Появилась идея, реализации.

```
static readonly List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> tupleList = new()
{
   new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("4Game", "Launcher", "Copyright (c) аа 2018", "1.0.0.1"),
   new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("asdfasdf", "кк", "Copyright (c) ып 2018", "1.0.0.2"),
   new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("4Gasdfggame", "чч", "Copyright (c) мв 2018", "1.0.0.3"),
};

 Console.WriteLine(tupleList[0].Item1);
 Console.WriteLine(tupleList[0].Item2);
 Console.WriteLine(tupleList[0].Item3);
```

Как сделать из списка чтобы за места `tupleList[0]` выпадало во все поля число ?
В списке 3 записи, если выпало 2 то записать `tupleList[1]` и.т.д

```
Console.WriteLine(tupleList[1].Item1);
Console.WriteLine(tupleList[1].Item2);
Console.WriteLine(tupleList[1].Item3);
```

Comment: Сохдайте класс с полями или свойствами. Создайте массив или список такого типа.

Comment: @aepot, я сначала подумал что можно создать список в `List<string>` или `Dictionary` или в `Tuple` занести список как-то и потом как их доставать от туда, тут я затупил. Сейчас вообще даже не понимаю что как)))

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyObject {
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public string Copyright;
    public string Version;
    
    public MyObject(string name, string type, string copyright, string ver){
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Copyright = copyright;
        Version = ver;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var someObjList = new List<MyObject>() {
        new MyObject("4Game", "Launcher", "Copyright (c) 2018", "1.0.0.264"),
        new MyObject("asdfasdf", "Launcher", "Copyright (c) 2018", "1.0.0.264"),
        new MyObject("4Gasdfggame", "Launcher", "Copyright (c) 2018", "1.0.0.264")
    };

}
```

Comment: Наверное тут конструктора не хватает, а как его вызывать тогда правильно?

Comment: Зачем здесь `struct`? Использойте класс, проблем меньше будет. Для версии есть тип `System.Version`.